# d3.js how to select elements according to a sublist of objects?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a huge hierarchy as input data. I manage visualization with (only) **d3.js** library. Beside another view, I display a table of data.
I need to modify lines according to an event.

In my example below, I want to **color** the **lines** corresponding to the subtree of the clicked node.

http://jsfiddle.net/dqpwgvmk/2/

```
var dataIN =
    {"name":"R","value":0,"children":[
     {"name":"F","value":42,"children":[]},
     {"name":"K","value":0,"children":[
      {"name":"H","value":10,"children":[
       {"name":"E","value":6,"children":[]},
       {"name":"D","value":4,"children":[]}
      ]},
      {"name":"J","value":0,"children":[
       {"name":"I","value":0,"children":[
        {"name":"C","value":3,"children":[]},
        {"name":"G","value":5,"children":[
         {"name":"B","value":2,"children":[]},
         {"name":"A","value":8,"children":[]}
        ]}
       ]}
      ]}
     ]}
    ]};
var nodes = d3.layout.treemap().nodes(dataIN);

/*create table*/
d3.select("body").append("table")
  .selectAll("tr").data(nodes).enter().append("tr")
  .attr("class",function(d){return "n"+d.name+"-"+d.value;})
  .attr("title",function(d){return d.name;})
  .selectAll("td").data(["name","value","button"]).enter().append("td")
    .attr("class",function(d){return d;});
//fill name
d3.selectAll(".name").data(nodes)
  .text(function(d){return d.name;});
//fill value
d3.selectAll(".value").data(nodes)
  .text(function(d){return d.value;});
//fill button
d3.selectAll(".button").data(nodes)
  .append("button").text("subtree")
  .on("click",function(d){return color(d);});

/*getsubtree*/
function getSubtree(n,ns) {
//get a list of all nodes in subtree of n, n included
 if(n.children) {
   n.children.forEach(function(c){
     ns = getSubtree(c,ns); 
   }); 
 }
 ns.push(n);
 return ns;
}

/*color*/
function color(n) {
    //reset
    d3.selectAll("tr").style("background-color","");
    //set
    var sub = getSubtree(n,[]);
    console.log("sub",sub);
    sub.forEach(function(d){
        d3.select(".n"+d.name+"-"+d.value)
          .style("background-color","#800080");
    });
}
```

I have not found a "short way" to select all the descendant of one node with d3.js. As you see, my DOM elements are "tr", so flat list.

To solve this, my approach is to filter nodes "from the data" (with hierarchy).
Then "select DOM elements" that correspond.

The example below works. I list subtree's nodes by recurse walk in my data tree. Then select each corresponding DOM element.

My problem is in case of huge data, the `d3.select()` in `sub.forEach()` loop take many times.

A investigate `d3.select().filter()` and `d3.select().data(values,Key())` but I have not find a solution to filter DOM elements according to a list of nodes.

Is there a way in d3 ?

Thanks Maxime HEBRARD

Comment: how damned ... the time consuming part of my code is not from the forEach() -_-.. It come from outside part that is not due to data manipulation with d3.js... 
So my main problem is solve (sorry for useless question - I do not know how to delete / edit it)
Still If you know a smarter way to select dom element according to a sub-data list, i'm still interresting

Comment: unless you are going to call getSubTree many many times, I don't think any optimization (eg memoization: save subresults into each element) will help with responsiveness

Comment: Another thing you could do is to change the recursive call to getSubTree into an iterative function (while loop with queue), then save the result to the current node (memoize). this way the answer to getSubTree for a specific node is only calculated once regardless of how many times u click

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331: I agree, I don't think that the recursive call in getSubTree is a problem. (Beside I notice your suggestion of memoize). I just wish to don't use forEach with d3.js. One paradigm sounds like "modify all nodes at the same time", that is opposite way of forEach loop.